# Error al copiar una una celda a otra con macro?

Tags: excel, vb

Buen dia.

Tengo el siguiente detalle:
Cuando una celda tenga una **P** la copie y la pegue en una hoja llamada **"temporal"** en la primera celda vacia. Y asi cada vez que encuentre una **P**.

Les dejo el codigo:

```
 Sub CopiarPegar()
 Dim celda As Object
 Dim rango As Range
 Dim UltimaFila As Long
 UltimaFila = 0
 UltimaFila = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Range("A1").End(XlDirection.xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
 Set rango = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cambium").Range("BN9:BN179")

 For Each celda In rango
    If celda = "P" Then MsgBox "Encontrado"
       celda.Copy
       'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0).Select'
       'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Range("A1").End(xlUp).Offset(0, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll'
       'ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Range("A1").Offset(1, 0) = 1'
       UltimaFila.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
       UltimaFila = UltimaFila + 1
  Next celda
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Select
  End Sub
```

Cuando la ejecuto me arroja un error en `UltimaFila.PasteSpecial xlPasteAll`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Comment: Este valor en dónde lo declaras y asignas xlPasteAll?

Comment: @Bicho Ese valor lo toma de la Hoja **Cambium** cada vez que una celda tenga **P** la copia.

Answer (score 1):

Lo solucione de la siguiente manera:

```
 Sub CopiarPegar()
 Dim celda As Object
 Dim rango As Range

 Set rango = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Cambium").Range("BN9:BN179")

 For Each celda In rango
    If celda = "P" Then ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(XlDirection.xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = celda.Value

 Next celda
 ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("temporal").Select
 End Sub
```